# Error: "Required value 'networkOffers' missing at $" For Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-json, moshi

I keep getting this Error call
[image]

Yet I'm not sure where to look to fix it. I have a raw JSON file in my Res Folder under the directory "Raw"
[image]

The Error is coming at my Repository

```
class C51Repository {


    private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()


    suspend fun getAllOffers(context: Context): List<Offer> {
        delay(2_000)

        val json = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.c51).bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }

        val offerList = moshi.adapter(C51::class.java).fromJson(json) //<- RIGHT HERE
        return offerList!!.networkOffers.map {
            Offer(
                cash_back = it.cash_back,
                image_url = it.image_url,
                name = it.name,
                offer_id = it.offer_id
            )
        }
    }



}
```

Here's the JSON file
[image]

Any Help is appreciated, Thanks.

P.S. I read that it could be a Moshi bug, but I don't know how to go about fixing the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the naming of the variables. I had name some variables different than the one called in the raw files. MAKE SURE YOU GET THOSE VARIABLE NAMES CORRECTLY